# @CreationTimeStamp and @UpdateTimeStamp not working with LocalDate, only have null values

Tags: java, hibernate, localdate, creation-timestamp

I have the following code in my entity class

```
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDate dateAdded;
    @JsonProperty("last_edited")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDate lastEdited;
```

However, when it comes to posting to the database, I am only getting null values for the two columns.

[image]
[image]

I am using Java 18 and spring-boot-starter-jpa

Edit: haven't figured out what's causing the problem... going to add the local date in the service instead for now...

```
        var sql = """
                INSERT INTO public.recipe ("name", "instructions", "date_added", "last_edited")
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                """;
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        recipeDTO.setDateAdded(localDateTime);
        recipeDTO.setLastEdited(localDateTime);
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                recipeDTO.getName(),
                recipeDTO.getInstructions(),
                localDateTime,
                localDateTime
        );
```

Comment: Dit you register the listener/interceptor that fills those fields or did you only slap on those annotations? Or in other words did you follow proper steps as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: the latter :/ could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: oh actually I do have ```@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)``` for my entity class

Comment: You also need `@EnableJpaAuditing` if I recall correctly.

Comment: unfortunately adding that doesn't work either

Comment: Also a column for an update timestamp that cannot be updated isn't that a bit weird? If it doesn't add those dates you must be doing something strange in storing those entities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `updatable = false` part as Hibernate will exclude assignments to these columns in update statements. So even if you do update the entity fields, the data will not be updated in the database.